# ArcGIS Server 10.0 too slow to generate cache tiles

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I want to define the zoom level scale for my arcgis web map, but it seems that I should build the cache tiles first (in ArcMap). I have waited for 2 hours but the cache status is still maintain in 0%. I was wondering if this is normal? Thanks.

Details:

- All files in TIFF (elevation map): (28,4 GB)
- ArcGIS Server 10.0 Enterprise Windows 7 32 bit.
- In *Analyze Map* 10 Warnings and 7 Messages
- 7 scales

How to speed it up?

Comment: try caching a scale or two for a start and see if it progresses.

Comment: I trying use only two scales, still 0%

Comment: I'd recommend working off some of those warnings and messages first.